Relative pronouns that single things out
I know that relative pronoun clauses can single things out of a larger group, but I am wondering if the context can change the effect. For example, (These are the sentences I made up)
Example 1
The ones on the list are the most advanced high-speed battleships around the world. There are about 35 of them. The first one is the most advanced high-speed battleship that most European navies use.
A: Among the advanced high-speed battleships in the world, this one is the one most European navies use.
B: Among the high-speed battleships most European navies use, this one is the most advanced.
Example 2
This is the list of several high-speed battleships currently in service in NATO naval forces. The first one is the most advanced high-speed battleship that most European navies use.
A: Among the advanced high-speed battleships in the world, this one is the one most European navies use.
B: Among the high-speed battleships most European navies use, this one is the most advanced.
Which option fits the meaning for example 1 and which for example 2?

"this" is a demonstrative adjective in "this one".  Without context, using "this" is like pointing at something in the dark. No one can see what you're pointing at.  Those statements (A,B) cannot stand alone.  Are you trying to refer back to "the first one on the list"?   If so, it would be better to say "That one".

I agree with @TimR. Relative pronouns do in fact appear in a couple of those sentences: A high-speed battleship that most European navies use. But this is a minor component of your examples and I suspect that's not what you are talking about. Clarification will be helpful.

Current terminology is "demonstrative determinative".

While both A and B may appear to mean the same thing, they have different points to make. When using the preposition "among," you imply that the subject of the sentence is part of a group. When a group is already mentioned, it's more natural to use that group as the subject to give new information.
In Example 1, the list is about the most advanced high-speed battleships overall. A native speaker would probably use A because the fact that European navies use it most is new information and not the main idea.
In Example 2, the same principle applies. The list is about European battleships, so B would be more natural because the most advanced ship is a minor fact rather than the purpose of a particular work.
If both lists were provided, either sentence could be used, depending on what you want to emphasize.
